# Specific foreign_key in Rails association not as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

Using Rails 3.2. I have the following table where `abc_id` should be referred to `xyz_id`. (Note: I don't have control on changing the continent table.)

```
# shop table
id: 1 # primary
abc_id: 345

# continent table
xyz_id: 1 # primary
desc: "lalala"

xyz_id: 345 # primary
desc: "lorem"
```

My association:

```
# shop.rb
has_one :continent, foreign_key: 'xyz_id'

# continent.rb
self.primary_key = "xyz_id"
belongs_to :shop, foreign_key: 'abc_id'
```

but when I run the following, I get this:

```
@shop = Shop.find(1)
@shop.continent
# >> SELECT `continent`.* FROM `continent` WHERE `continent`.`xyz_id` = 1 LIMIT 1
```

Why is the `continent`.`xyz_id` not `345`? What have I done wrong?

Comment: `:foreign_key:` might be the problem; that leading `:` shouldn't be there. I think it might be parsing oddly. In fact it should be a syntax error, so maybe it'd just a typo in your code.

Comment: Sorry, it was my typo in my question, not in my code. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by specifying `primary_key` in `shop.rb`:

```
has_one :continent, foreign_key: 'xyz_id', primary_key: 'abc_id'
```

Comment: Odd scenario. Nice catch.

Answer (score 0):

The `foreign_key` (and `primary key`) should always be the same on both sides of an association.

In your case, in `shop.rb` the association should be:

`has_one :continent, foreign_key: 'abc_id'`

Comment: I think it's likely this is true, but I can't find anything to back up my assumption. It's certainly a good idea, as is using default naming conventions for both primary and foreign keys, but it seems that Rails provides a mechanism to do weird things if you really want to.

Comment: It doesn't work. I have tried switching around. the `abc_id` should refer to `xyz_id`, but instead it is `spot_id` to `xyz_id`. I have no control on the `continent` table.